# Twitter Widget not working

Tags: javascript, twitter

I created a twitter widget and plugged it into a page. It works fine on my computer, but not on any others. I don't even know where to begin to debug this.

Here is the twitter-generated code:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/NavigatorPG" data-widget-id="256786483787218945">Tweets by @NavigatorPG</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Here is the page with the widget http://navigatorplanninggroup.org/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am on the same problem. Your question addresses multiple issues. To debug JS you need to toggle the JavaScript in your browser and a debugger like "firebug"-a plugin to numerous browsers. This will not help for this bugged widget due to numerous issues: the broken link from Twitter in the `<script>` src attribute that refers to an invalid link with no protocol. Note the absent `http:!for future refence you can visit the valid link and copy&paste it into your own .js (JavaScript file and refer to it via an absolute or relative path **this does not work with this widget.** Switch JavaScript on and you will see the widget as expected. Either the widget code is bugged or twitter i falsely stating that their widget doesn't need JavaScript when it does.